# Cannot Figure out whats wrong with this code [python 3x]

Tags: python

```
def N_C(question,choices):
  N_C_choices_to_num = []
  N_C_choice_count_max = len(choices)
  N_C_choice_count_min = N_C_choice_count_max - N_C_choice_count_max
  print(question)
  for i in range (N_C_choice_count_min, N_C_choice_count_max):
    print(N_C_choice_count_min+i+1,".", choices[i])
    N_C_choices_to_num.append(N_C_choice_count_min+i+1)
  def N_C_restart_input():
    N_C_choices_num = input(">>>")
    if str(N_C_choices_num) in str(N_C_choices_to_num):
      return "something"
    elif str(N_C_choices_num) not in str(N_C_choices_to_num):
      N_C_restart_input()
    else:
      return(N_C_choices_num)
  N_C_restart_input()



answer = N_C("Hey Bro, how are you?",["Fine","Dead","Okay..."])
print(answer)
```

I have been working on this, and I am not sure why it returns "none" instead of the variable I set it to return,

Any help is helpful, thanks if anyone could help because I cannot figure it out myself even though it is most likely extremely simple.

Comment: We can't even run the code without literally typing it in to see the error, imagine how stumped *we* are.

Comment: Add the code, not a link with a screenshot

Comment: @timgeb I run it on Repl, it gives this output http://prntscr.com/lj80jw, it should be outputting the number you choose in the input.

Comment: Sorry I was not being explicit: post the code as text, not as a picture, please.

Comment: Your code has three conditionals and only two of them return.

Comment: Sorry I posted the code as text.

Comment: @silverslash do you mean I need to return for the 2 things in the function like: function("this need to be returned", "and this need to be returned"),

Comment: It needs to be `return N_C_restart_input()` and you'll get your return value. Now whether or not it's the correct return value, I don't know. The code looks badly written and there could be several other mistakes.

Comment: @ThePatchWokHoax don't worry about SilverSlash's EARLIER comment, that's not your problem.

Comment: His last comment, however, is absolutely correct, as outlined in my answer

Comment: @Caleb H. This worked perfectly, thank you, I have made this mistake so many times before and never figured it out, Using functions inside functions can something confuse me when outputting stuff.

Comment: @SilverSlash Sorry, I am just experimenting with python by making functions to make other things easier, if the code is a bit shoddy now I am sure I will get better and learn new tricks when I am not trying to clear up errors and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you aren't actually returning any value. 
Your `N_C_restart_input` function returns a value, but your `N_C`  function never does. Your last line in the `N_C` function should probably look like this:

`return N_C_restart_input()`